# Using Transformations results in a new LiveData value after the screen is rotated, etc

Tags: android

I have two number vars - number and number2:

```
val number = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
    DummyDataFactory.getData()
        .toFlowable()
)

val number2: LiveData<Int> = Transformations.switchMap(number) { number ->
    LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
        DummyDataFactory.getData2(number).toFlowable()
    )
}
```

Functions DummyDataFactory.getData() and DummyDataFactory.getData2() are here:

```
class DummyDataFactory {

companion object {

    fun getData(): Single<Int> {
        return Single.just((0..10).random())
    }

    fun getData2(number1: Int): Single<Int> {
        return Single.just((11..20).random())
    }
}
```

}

It works as expected before screen rotation or other similar lifecycle event is happening, after screen rotation number is remains the same and number2 getting new value because getData2() function is triggers, how to use Transformations for getData2() not triggering after screen rotation and etc.?

Comment: Because you use `switchMap`, which returns a new `LiveData<T>` object.  On rotation `number` (source) will emit its current value, i.e replay(1), that will then invoke all downstream operators, thus producing a new emission of a random value.  Where as `number` will replay its cached value, and it does not have any transformations.  You should reverve the order and convert to live data last  i.e Rx Publisher --> transformations ---> to live data

Comment: @MarkKeen, so how should I write code to solve this? what number2 should be equal to?